# django and postgres: sqlclear always fails to delete constraint

Tags: django, postgresql, django-mptt, django-manage.py

django 1.6 with postgres 9.1
When trying to re-init a db I typically use the management command sqlclear so I can target tables specific to an app.
In django 1.6 and postgres, whenever I use this command, it will always fail when it attempts to delete a constraint. causing the sqlclear to rollback.

I'm also using django-mptt and django model-utils.

Wondering if this has something to do with it.

Does anybody else have this problem?